# animated effect for fadein/fadeout using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fadein, fadeout

To understand my code please visit this page:

**Please click on packaging filter first**

http://codepen.io/mariomez/pen/qNrzAr?editors=0010

It's a simplified animated filtering method.

Each red box might have more than one classes as an identifier for the filter.
My goal with this code is to achieve a nice animated way for fade-in and for fade-out. For now I managed to do this only for fade-in.

Even though I wrote the animation for fade-out I can't use it properly in the JS code.

**Example for 1 filter:** I want all classes except "packaging" to fade-out nicely and have the packaging class fade-in.

**jQuery CODE**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".filter-logo").click(function(){
        $(".all").fadeOut(normal,addClass('animated fadeOutEffect'));
        $(".logo").fadeIn(normal,addClass('animated fadeInEffect'));
    });
    $(".filter-website").click(function(){
        $(".all").fadeOut();
        $(".website").fadeIn().addClass('animated fadeInEffect');
    });

    $(".filter-packaging").click(function(){
        $(".all").fadeOut();
        $(".packaging").fadeIn().addClass('animated fadeInEffect');
    });

    $(".filter-forsale").click(function(){
        $(".all").fadeOut();
        $(".forsale").fadeIn().addClass('animated fadeInEffect');
    });

    $(".filter-all").click(function(){
        $(".all").fadeOut();
        $(".logo, .website, .packaging, .forsale, .all").fadeIn().addClass('animated fadeInEffect');
    });
});
```

**Trying to use the fade-in animation: (FAILED)**

```
$(".all").not('.packaging').fadeOut().addClass('animated  fadeOutEffect');
        $(".packaging").fadeIn().addClass('animated fadeInEffect');
    });
```

**How can I improve this code?**

Comment: try to sequence the fading like: `$(".all").fadeOut(function(){$(".logo").fadeIn().addClass('animated fadeInDown');});` also you could give __[delay time](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp)__ to it so it's not that fast...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL In your example I can't use fadeInUp which is the opposite animation that I need to use for when fading-out. I need an animation for boxes that fade out and one for boxes that fade in. I already have the fade in animation.

Comment: (Keep in mind that I changed the names of classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your example.
http://codepen.io/jammer99/pen/mEQabN
Essentially you need to set fadeout to finish within 0 seconds forcefully, additionally since you have already used css to generate the animation, you should use `hide()` and `show()` instead of `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`

here's the updated code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".all").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("animated")
      })
      $(".filter-logo").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".all").removeClass('fadeInEffect').addClass("fadeOutEffect").hide(0);
        $(".logo").show(0).removeClass("fadeOutEffect").addClass('fadeInEffect');
      });

      $(".filter-website").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".all").removeClass('fadeInEffect').addClass("fadeOutEffect").hide(0)
        $(".website").show(0).removeClass("fadeOutEffect").addClass('fadeInEffect');
      });

      // UPDATE CODE - START ////////////
      $(".filter-packaging").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".all").removeClass('fadeInEffect').addClass("fadeOutEffect").hide(0);
        $(".packaging").show(0).removeClass("fadeOutEffect").addClass('fadeInEffect');

      });
      // UPDATE CODE - END ////////////

      $(".filter-forsale").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".all").removeClass('fadeInEffect').addClass("fadeOutEffect").hide(0);
        $(".forsale").show(0).removeClass("fadeOutEffect").addClass('fadeInEffect');
      });

      $(".filter-all").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".all").removeClass('fadeOutEffect').addClass("fadeInEffect").show(0)
      });
    });
```

---

**EDIT** : Here is updated code. http://codepen.io/jammer99/pen/mEQabN?editors=0010

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".all").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("animated")
  })
  $(".filter-logo").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".all").removeClass('fadeInEffect').addClass("fadeOutEffect")
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".all").hide(0)
      $(".logo").stop().show(0).removeClass("fadeOutEffect").addClass('fadeInEffect');
    }, 500);
  });

  $(".filter-website").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".all").removeClass('fadeInEffect').addClass("fadeOutEffect")
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".all").hide(0)
      $(".website").stop().show(0).removeClass("fadeOutEffect").addClass('fadeInEffect');
    }, 500);
  });

  $(".filter-packaging").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".all").removeClass('fadeInEffect').addClass("fadeOutEffect")
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".all").hide(0)
      $(".packaging").stop().show(0).removeClass("fadeOutEffect").addClass('fadeInEffect');
    }, 500);
  });

  $(".filter-forsale").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".all").removeClass('fadeInEffect').addClass("fadeOutEffect")
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".all").hide(0)
      $(".forsale").stop().show(0).removeClass("fadeOutEffect").addClass('fadeInEffect');
    }, 500);
  });

  $(".filter-all").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".all").removeClass('fadeInEffect').addClass("fadeOutEffect")
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".all").show(0).removeClass("fadeOutEffect").addClass('fadeInEffect');
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. When it comes to visual results, still this is not different from what I had (more or less) and the most important is that the "fadeout" animation effect is not shown properly, it's like there is no effect at all when it should be something like the fadein animation in reverse.

Comment: I awarded you with the 50 points. This looks great now. Thanks.

Comment: :) glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

For your Example for 1 filter, you're saying you want "packaging" to be the only one to not fade out, but then have "packaging" fade in even though it didn't fade out?

I'm going to assume you want everything to fade out, then have "packaging" fade in. You can do so by calling the `fadeIn` for "packaging" inside a callback when you `fadeOut` `.all`.

Edit:

So the `fadeOut` function takes a completion callback, a function that will run after the `fadeOut` animation completes. You just need to pass in an anonymous function to the `fadeOut` parameter, and inside that function do what you want to do after the animation completes:

```
$(".filter-packaging").click(function(){
    $(".all").fadeOut(function() {
        $(".packaging").fadeIn().addClass('animated fadeInEffect');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you give me an example because I fail to use both animations.

Comment: This is helpful but I don't get how can I run the fadeout first AND the fade-out-effect too and THEN run the fade in etc etc.. 
The issue is that If I add  a class for fade-out then it will remain even if I add a new class for fade-in.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your css and js animations are clashing. You should probably stick to one or the other. Also both js animations are running at the same time `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

An option is to wait until the `fadeOut` animation ends before starting the `fadeIn` animation. You can do that with a timeout.

In the example below the function `hideThenShow` waits until the of the `fadeOut` animation (500ms) then runs the `fadeIn` on the selected elements.

As a bonus you could loop through your filters and your list elements instead of repeating the `hideThenShow` function in the example.

Hope it helps

```js
function hideThenShow($clickedElement, $elementsToShow){
  var duration = 500;
  $clickedElement.click(function(){
    $('.all').fadeOut(duration);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $elementsToShow.fadeIn();
    },duration);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  var filterLogo        = $(".filter-logo");
  var filterWebsite     = $(".filter-website");
  var filterPackaging   = $('.filter-packaging');
  var filterForsale     = $('.filter-forsale');
  var filterAll         = $(".filter-all");
  var websiteElemetns   = $('.website');
  var logoElements      = $(".logo");
  var packagingElements = $('.packaging');    
  var forsaleElements   = $('.forsale');
  var allElements       = $(".all");  
  
  hideThenShow(filterLogo, logoElements);
  hideThenShow(filterWebsite, websiteElemetns);
  hideThenShow(filterPackaging, packagingElements);
  hideThenShow(filterForsale, forsaleElements);
  hideThenShow(filterAll, allElements);
  
});
```

```css
.ullist li {width:100px;background:#f00; height:100px; display:block; float:left;clear:none; margin:25px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="secmenu">
 <ul>
        <a href="#" class="filter-all"><li>All</li></a>
        <a href="#" class="filter-logo"><li>Logo</li></a>
        <a href="#" class="filter-website"><li>Website</li></a>
        <a href="#" class="filter-packaging"><li>Packaging</li></a>
        <a href="#" class="filter-forsale"><li>For sale</li></a>
</ul>
</div>


  <ul class="ullist">
<li class="website all">text</li>
<li class="website all">text</li>
<li class="website all">text</li>
<li class="packaging all">text</li>
<li class="packaging all">text</li>
<li class="logo all">text</li>
<li class="logo all">text</li>
<li class="logo all">text</li>
<li class="logo all">text</li>
<li class="logo all">text</li>
<li class="forsale all">text</li>
    
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but more or less what i have (without the animations) is exact the same with what  you proposed (i mean the result). The problem is that i don't like just a fade animation so that's  why I wrote a css for this. I want to incorporate the animations for fade in and out into js.

Comment: I did manage to add an animation for fadein (animation is not the fadein itself but the css which is attached to that) . My plan is to do this nicely for fadeout too, not remove them from the code